# React Native app.json Duplicate Resources

Tags: android, react-native

I am just creating a react native project with

```
react-native init somename
```

Then creating folder with

```
mkdir android/app/src/main/assets
```

Then creating bundle

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

After all that I look for drawable folder but can't find any in

```
\android\app\src\main\res
```

Then I open the project with Android Studioand try to generate signed apk, creating key and click yes then it gives eror

```
"\android\app\build\generated\res\react\release\raw\app.json: Error: Duplicate resources"
```

It show erors with  2 files

```
\app\src\main\res\raw\app.json
{
  "name": "somename",
  "displayName": "somename"
}
```

```
[raw/app] \android\app\src\main\res\raw\app.json    
[raw/app] \android\app\build\generated\res\react\release\raw\app.json: Error: Duplicate resources
{
  "name": "somename",
  "displayName": "somename"
}
```

I searched but I can not find any solution. Can anyone please help me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, what worked for me was:

1. Go to folder \android\app\src\main\res
2. Delete the raw folder

*Explanation:*

This folder generates when you run the command:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

This generates multiple folders with the resources of your app, but you already have them in the src folder because of how react works, and therefore the error appears.

Deleting it does not affect your apk or bundle.

Hope it helps.

Comment: At leat I was trying to delete one of the app.json while waiting the answer. It created apk and It works fine on my Xiaomi mi5s 
But I send the apk to my friends phone(android) when click the apk to install It says
"You may not have a proper app for viewing this content"

Comment: Okay Wp is not permit to install apk. It solved thank you for all.

Answer (score 0):

```
Go to your android/app/src/res/ ===> delete all drawable-hdpi,mdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi,xxxhdpi and raw folders.

then run the below cmd
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```